# как сделать, что бы docker в WSL создавал файлы\папки от имени пользователя системы?

Tags: docker, wsl

docker в WSL создает файлы\папки от пользователя root

docker desktop в windows 11

в WSL debian 12

файлы\папки, которые создаются внутри контейнера(логи, другие файлы) создаются от пользователя рут в хост системе (debian)

нужно, что бы они создавались от имени пользователя системы

что и где нужно прописать(права на что поменять, что бы получить данное поведение (как в linux системах в rootless mode)

например:

внутри контейра создаю файл 1.txt

в системе он создается от пользователя root

подозреваю, что проблема может быть в этом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мета-информация (владелец, права доступа, время доступа и пр.) файлов (и директорий) хранится в соответствующих им [inode](https://man.archlinux.org/man/inode.7.ru)

Когда файл монтируется в контейнер, то внутри контейнера файловые операции происходят с тем же самым inode

[image: inode]

Соответственно, если внутри контейнера пользователь с UID 0 создаст файл, то в inode будет записана информация о владельце с UID 0. С точки хрения хоста владельцем файла также будет юзер с UID 0, с сооветствии с теми мета-данными, что были прочитаны из inode

[image: inode]

Поэтому, если необходимо, чтобы владельцем создаваемых в контейнере файлов был некий пользователь хостовой системы, то в контейнере необходимо запускать процесс от юзера с таким же UID, как у целевого пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: извиняюсь за поздний ответ.
Я понял, спасибо :)